# Barban-Davenport-Halberstam for 1 mod q

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for a version of the Barban-Davenport-Halberstam theorem which only focuses on the residue class of 1 modulo $q$, i.e. something that bounds
$$\sum_{q\leq Q}\left(\psi(x;q,1)-x/\phi(q)\right)^2.$$

Comment: By Brun-Titchmarsh, each term is $O(x^2/\phi(q)^2)$, so the sum is dominated by the first few terms.  From Siegel-Walfisz and Brun-Titchmarsh one obtains a bound of $O_A(x^2 \log^{-A} x)$ for any $A$, and conversely such a bound implies Siegel-Walfisz for the $1 \hbox{ mod } q$ classes.  It's unlikely that this is improvable with current technology.  Perhaps you would like to use the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem instead?

Comment: I am mostly interested in large $q$ which makes Bombieri-Vinogradov prohibitive. Basically, what I was looking for is something to the effect that a very strong version of Linnik's theorem, that there are many primes congruent to $1\mod q$ and smaller than $q^{1+\epsilon}$, holds for the typical $q$.

Comment: If you are interested in large q then you probably want to study a different sum than the one indicated, since as I said it is dominated by the small $q$.  Absent some major breakthrough in the Siegel-Walfisz theorem, the contribution of the small $q \leq \log^{O(1)} x$ will not be better than $x^2 \log^{-A} x$, so the best bound one gets on average for $\psi(x;q,1)-x/\phi(q)$ for $q \sim Q$ by this approach is $O( x Q^{-1/2} \log^{-A} x)$, which is inferior to Brun-Titchmarsh when $Q$ is larger than polylogarithmic.